# Vue.js pass bound data to click event handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a v-for loop where I loop through some data returned from my api and set the key equal to the id of the object in the api. Now I want to create a click event that gets the v-bind:key value of the clicked element. This is so that I can use it to find all the data for this object in my posts[] array. But I don't know if it is possible to do this, if so how?

Here's my code;

```
<template>
    <div id="summary_section">
        <h2>Summary</h2>

        <div id="summary_board">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="head">
                    <h3>Opportunities</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="body">
                    <div class="post" 
                        v-for="post in posts"
                        v-bind:key="post._id"
                        v-on:click="getPostData"
                    >
                        <p>{{ post._id }}</p>
                        <p class="company">{{ post.company_name }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        data() {
            return{
                posts: []
            };
        },
        created() {
            axios.get('http://localhost:5000/')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data);
                const data = res.data;
                this.posts = data;
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        },
        methods: {
            UpdatePosts() {
                axios.get('http://localhost:5000/')
                    .then(res => {
                        // console.log(res);
                        const data = res.data;
                        this.posts = data;
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error));
            },
            getPostData(event) {
                console.log(event);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass that `id` as parameter inside the event click handler as follows :

```
 v-on:click="getPostData($event,post._id)"
```

the method handler :

```
 getPostData(event,id) {
            console.log(event,id);
}
```

if you don't need the event object you could do that like :

```
 v-on:click="getPostData(post._id)"
```

and

```
 getPostData(id) {
            console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks just what I needed. No I don't think I need the event object so I'll remove that

Answer (score 4):

You can update your template like:

```
v-on:click="getPostData(post._id)"
```

and then access this value like:

```
getPostData(id) {
    console.log(id);
}
```

Also, `@click` is just shorthand for `v-on:click` directive, so you can also use that if you like:

```
@click="getPostData(post._id)"
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. Boussadjra Brahim just managed to get the same solution in first so I'll give them the accepted answer

Comment: No worries at all. I am glad that your issue is resolved at least. Have a nice day :)